# Changing to newest or oldest directory -- csh idiom not working in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Please let me know why the following command works in csh mode and not in bash.

Bash:

```
~ $ cd `ls -ltr | grep ^d | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'`
bash: cd: synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5: No such file or directory
~ $ pwd
/home/mkumar
```

after changing to csh:

```
~ $ csh
CSH > cd `ls -ltr | grep ^d | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'`
CSH > pwd
/home/mkumar/synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5
```

Comment: It's a very bad idea to build any logic that depends upon the output of `ls`.

Comment: Also, I am not sure how `cd ls -ltr | grep ^d | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'` ever works.  May be you meant `cd $(cd ls -ltr | grep ^d | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}')`.

Comment: @codeforester That was just an issue with the question's formatting.

Comment: I can't reproduce; the same command works fine in `bash`.

Comment: I understand that it would be a bad code to use output of ls. This command is just my alias to chdir to the latest directory. I use similar commands to do less and vi, none of these work for bash however they always work for csh mode

I just have a file called .cd_last_file and then have an alias cdl="source .cd_last_file"
similary for vi and less

Comment: See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).

Comment: @mohitkumar, the first place to start in figuring out why they don't work with bash is to run `set -x`, then use your alias, and collect its *exact* output.

Comment: @mohitkumar, ...or, better, you could use an approach that doesn't require `ls`.

Comment: Thanks Charles Duffy

Comment: BTW, I have to imagine that part of the problem with the original is `ls -r` giving you directory names that aren't actually direct children of your current working directory. Is `synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5` *really* something that exists in your home directory?

Comment: If the last thing in output from `ls -lt` has spaces in its names, of course, that would cause problems as well.

Comment: Yes synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5 exists in home directory
by just changing the shell from bash for csh my aliases work

last directory name can be anything say "last_directory" obviously without spaces. It just happened that while typing the question I had synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5 as the last directory

Comment: Seeing the output of reproducing the failure after running `set -x`, as previously requested, would be informative.

Comment: ~ $ set -x file=`ls -ltr | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}' | tail -1`

~ $ echo $file

+ echo 'synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5'

synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5

~ $ cd $file

+ cd 'synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5'

bash: cd: synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code that relies on parsing `ls` [is innately bug-prone](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Don't do it.

The below gets a little fancy, reusing the same code to build both `cd_newest` and `cd_oldest` functions:

```
cd_by_test() {
  local test=$1 dir best_dir=
  shift
  (( "$#" == 0 )) && set -- */
  for dir; do dir=${dir%/}
    [[ -d "$dir" ]] || continue
    [[ $best_dir ]] || best_dir=$dir
    [ "$dir" "$test" "$best_dir" ] && best_dir=$dir
  done
  if [[ $best_dir ]]; then
    cd "$best_dir"
  else
    echo "No directory found" >&2
  fi
}

cd_newest() { cd_by_test -nt "$@"; }
cd_oldest() { cd_by_test -ot "$@"; }
```

Here, we're setting the operator to use two compare two files by assigning it to the variable `$test` within the `cd_by_test` function, and then using `[ "$dir" "$test" "$best_dir" ]` to apply that operator.

---

In the recently-amended version, we can also pick between a specific subset of directories:

```
cd_newest *-test.d/
```

...will `cd` to the newest `*-test.d` directory.

Comment: Just curious: why do you strip the trailing `/` from `dir`?

Comment: Purely personal aesthetic sensibilities with `set -x`; nothing compelling to it.

Comment: Could you please explain `test=$1` and its impact on the last line of the loop inside the function?

Comment: @codeforester `cd_by_test` is parameterized by the operator used to compare two directories. Passing `-nt` checks if `$dir` is newer than the best directory found so far; passing `-ot` checks if is is *older* than instead. Storing the operator in a variable instead of hard-coding it is what necessitates the switch from `[[ ... ]]` to `[ ... ]`.

Answer (score 2):

Unsolicited plug for `zsh` (as justification, I'd suggest considering `zsh` if you are just interested in moving to a shell other than `csh`).

```
% cd *(/om[1])
% pwd
/home/mkumar/synopsys_cache_L-2016.03-SP5
```

The parentheses following `*` contain various glob *qualifiers*:

- `/` limits the match to directories
- `om` sorts the expansion by modification time
- `[1]` selects only the first match

Comment: As much personal distaste as I have for zsh, that *is* cute. :)